Real-time Reflection Error of Circuit Switching on Voltage and Current Graph in Tkinter Matplotlib Integration
Here is what I want to realize result
I'm working on a project where I've integrated a Tkinter GUI with Matplotlib to monitor voltage and current in a circuit simulation. I have a manual switch button to simulate circuit faults by toggling the switch. However, I'm facing an issue where the voltage and current graphs don't reflect the real-time changes when I toggle the switch.
The code is as follows:
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

t_max = 10.0  # Maximum time (seconds)
fps = 20  # Frames per second
t = np.linspace(0, t_max, int(fps * t_max))  # Time sequence

# Circuit parameters
V_battery = 15  # Battery voltage (V)
R_load = 10  # Load resistance (ohms)

class CircuitSimulator:
    def __init__(self, t_values, initial_switch_state=True):
        self.t_values = t_values
        self.VoltageOverTime = np.full_like(t_values, V_battery)  # All time point voltages are initially battery voltage
        self.CurrentOverTime = np.full_like(t_values, V_battery / R_load)  # Initialize current array
        self.switch_states = np.ones_like(t_values, dtype=bool) * initial_switch_state  # Record the state of the switch at each time point
        self.previous_switch_state = initial_switch_state  # Record the previous switch state
        self.previous_switch_time_index = -1 # Initialize to -1, indicating no switch has been made

    def calculate_circuit_response(self, current_time_index):
        # Check if there is a switch change at the current time point
        if current_time_index > self.previous_switch_time_index:
            # Check if the switch state at the current time point is different from the previous time point
            if self.switch_states[current_time_index] != self.switch_states[current_time_index - 1]:
                self.previous_switch_state = self.switch_states[current_time_index]
                next_switch_index = current_time_index + np.argmax(self.switch_states[current_time_index:] != self.switch_states[current_time_index])
                if not self.previous_switch_state:
                    # Switch is open
                    self.VoltageOverTime[current_time_index:next_switch_index] = 0
                    self.CurrentOverTime[current_time_index:next_switch_index] = 0
                else:
                    # Switch is closed
                    self.VoltageOverTime[current_time_index:next_switch_index] = V_battery * np.ones_like(self.VoltageOverTime[current_time_index:next_switch_index])
                    self.CurrentOverTime[current_time_index:next_switch_index] = V_battery / R_load * np.ones_like(self.CurrentOverTime[current_time_index:next_switch_index])
                # Update the time index of the last switch change
                self.previous_switch_time_index = next_switch_index

    def toggle_switch_at_time(self, switch_time_index):
        if 0 <= switch_time_index < len(self.switch_states):
            # Only change the switch state at the specified time point and the defined time period after it
            end_of_simulation = min(switch_time_index + 1, len(self.switch_states))  # Prevent overflow
            self.switch_states[switch_time_index:end_of_simulation] = not self.switch_states[switch_time_index]
        else:
            raise IndexError(f"Invalid time index: {switch_time_index}. Maximum allowed index is {len(self.switch_states) - 1}")

# Create a new window class for integrating matplotlib charts with Tkinter GUI
class CircuitSimulationGUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set window title
        self.title("Circuit Operation Monitoring")

        # Create the main container
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Initialize the chart
        self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 6))
        self.V_line, = self.axs[0].plot([], [], label='Circuit Voltage (V)')
        self.I_line, = self.axs[1].plot([], [], label='Circuit Current (A)', color='r')
        for ax in self.axs:
            ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
            ax.set_ylabel('Value')
            ax.legend()

        # Embed the matplotlib chart into the Tkinter window
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=container)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        # Create the switch button
        self.manual_switch_button = tk.Button(master=self, text="Close Circuit", command=self.toggle_manual_switch)
        self.manual_switch_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Initialize the animation
        self.simulator = CircuitSimulator(t)
        self.ani = None  # Initialize the animation instance variable to None

        # Initialize state variables
        self.current_time_index = 0

        # Start the simulation
        self.start_simulation()

    def toggle_manual_switch(self):
        """
        Handle the click event of the manual switch button, toggle the switch state at the current time point and continue to affect subsequent states
        """
        # Get the index of the current time point
        current_index = int(self.current_time_index)

        # Toggle the switch state
        self.simulator.toggle_switch_at_time(current_index)
        self.simulator.calculate_circuit_response(current_index)

        # Update the button text and command
        if self.manual_switch_button["text"] == "Close Circuit":
            self.manual_switch_button["text"] = "Open Circuit"
        else:
            self.manual_switch_button["text"] = "Close Circuit"

        # Set the transition duration (assume 0.5 seconds)
        transition_duration = 0.5  # in seconds
        transition_frames = int(transition_duration * fps)

        # Get the start and end time indices of the transition
        start_index = current_index
        end_index = min(start_index + transition_frames, len(t))

        # Transition voltage and current arrays step by step
        for i in range(start_index, end_index):
            transition_ratio = (i - start_index) / transition_frames
            if self.manual_switch_button["text"] == "Open Circuit":  # If the circuit is opened
                # Transition from battery voltage and current to 0
                self.simulator.VoltageOverTime[i] = (1 - transition_ratio) * V_battery
                self.simulator.CurrentOverTime[i] = (1 - transition_ratio) * (V_battery / R_load)
            else:
                # Transition from 0 to battery voltage and current
                self.simulator.VoltageOverTime[i] = transition_ratio * V_battery
                self.simulator.CurrentOverTime[i] = transition_ratio * (V_battery / R_load)

        # Update the entire chart, pass the index of the current time point
        self.update_plot(current_index)  
        self.canvas.draw_idle()


    def start_simulation(self):
        # Use a more modern and compatible way to detect and control animation status
        if self.ani is None:
            self.ani = FuncAnimation(
                fig=self.fig,
                func=self.update_plot, # Pass the function instead of the method 
                frames=len(t),
                interval=200,
                blit=True
            )
            self.canvas.draw_idle()
        elif getattr(self.ani, '_is_running', False):  # Change here
            self.ani.event_source.stop()
            self.ani.event_source.start()
        else:
            self.ani.event_source.start()

    def update_plot(self, frame):
        self.simulator.calculate_circuit_response(frame)
        time = t[frame]
        
        V_circuit = self.simulator.VoltageOverTime[:frame+1]
        I_circuit = self.simulator.CurrentOverTime[:frame+1]

        self.V_line.set_data(t[:len(V_circuit)], V_circuit)
        self.I_line.set_data(t[:len(I_circuit)], I_circuit)
        self.axs[0].set_xlim(0, t_max)
        self.axs[1].set_xlim(0, t_max)
        self.axs[0].set_ylim(0, 20)
        self.axs[1].set_ylim(0, 2)
        print("Plot updated")  # Add this line of code to confirm if the chart has been updated
        print("Plot Voltage:", V_circuit[-1], "V")
        return self.V_line, self.I_line

# Create and start the GUI application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CircuitSimulationGUI()
    app.mainloop()


I've tried updating the voltage and current arrays based on the switch state inside the toggle_manual_switch method, followed by updating the plot. I expected the voltage and current graphs to dynamically update with each switch toggle, showing the changes in real-time. However, the graphs only update after the simulation ends, not during the simulation.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
